# Почему preg_replace срабатывает не всегда?

Tags: php

Вот код

```
$content = fopen("111.sql", "r");
$content=fread($content, filesize("111.sql"));
echo preg_replace('@http(.*)/uploads/(.*).jpg/@', 'http$1/uploads/$2.webp', $content);
file_put_contents("111.sql", $content);
```

http://sofuwa.ru/demo/111.txt

Comment: попробуйте сделать его менее жадным `'@http(.*?)/uploads/(.*?).jpg/@'`

Comment: А вообще-то, хорошо бы узнать когда не срабатывает

Comment: я указывал файл, удалили что ли, может ссылки запрещены http://sofuwa.ru/demo/111.txt

Comment: '@http(.*?)/uploads/(.*?).jpg/@' - так тоже самое

Comment: слеш после jpg уберите

Comment: почему? и почему срабатывает иногда

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ifp1xU/1