# Почему preg_replace то работает то нет?

Tags: php

Я уже задавал вопрос тут? [Почему preg_replace срабатывает не всегда?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1127261/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-preg-replace-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1948603_1127261)

```
$content = fopen("test.txt", "r");
$content=fread($content, filesize("test.txt"));
echo preg_replace('@http(.*?)/uploads/(.*?).jpg@', 'http$1/uploads/$2.webp', $content);
file_put_contents("test2.txt", $content);
```

Вроде ответили, но не работает на больших кусках БД, не понимаю почему. Может всё таки из за кириллицы, хотя в запросах нет кириллицы.
http://sofuwa.ru/demo/ - запуск скрипта.
http://sofuwa.ru/demo/test.txt
Можете у себя проверить.

И в зависимости от размера примера то работает echo то нет, то пустой экран, все ошибки включены, вообще не понятно почему и вы попробуйте не в сервисах для теста запросов, а в реальном скрипте, я пробовал на двух разных хостингах, не работает.

Иногда когда тестовый пример меньше, первые два не срабатывают, остальные замены срабатывают, когда больше кусок, вообще не работает. Представления не имею почему.

Нужно замену сделать, даже через notepad++ пытался

```
http(.*?)/uploads/(.*?).jpg
http/\1/uploads/\2.webp
```

не срабатывает почему то

Comment: 405 Not Allowed

Comment: поправил на txt теперь открывает, sql запрещено наверно шарить

Comment: вот так сделайте `http([^"]*?)/uploads/([^"]*?).jpg(?=\\")` все сработает

Comment: ```$content = fopen("test.txt", "r");
$content=fread($content, filesize("test.txt"));
echo preg_replace('@http([^"]*?)/uploads/([^"]*?).jpg(?=\\")@', 'http$1/uploads/$2.webp', $content);
file_put_contents("test2.txt", $content);``` так не работает. Попробуйте у себя сделать.

Comment: можно без lookahead  - `'@http([^"]*?)/uploads/([^"]*?).jpg@`  Не дожен лишнего захватывать

Comment: вообще то не работает, хз может файл слишком большой, я так понял у себя не пробовали

Answer (score 0):

При большом размере файла, как у вас, лучше читать и обрабатывать файл построчно. Например так:

```
$source = new SplFileObject('test.txt');
$result = new SplFileObject('test2.txt', 'w');
while (!$source->eof()) {
  $row = preg_replace('@(http[^"\' ]*/uploads/[^"\' ]*)\.jpe?g@i', "$1.webp", $source->fgets());
  $result->fwrite($row);
}
```

Само регулярное выражение я немного изменил, т.к. при использовании `(.*?)` выражение может работать не корректно, если в путях содержащих /uploads/ кроме файлов jpeg есть и файлы с другими расширениями.

И обратите внимание, что `preg_replace` не изменяет исходную строку, а возвращает измененное значение. По-этому вы в своем коде записываете в файл test2.txt не измененную строку $content